# Vim 8 terminal change width

Tags: terminal

1. Suppose I run

   ```
   :terminal someprg_wide_output
   ```

   the output is wrapped by current terminal window size wrapped hard way, so `:set nowrap` there can't help
2. When I run same program not from vim  like this:

   ```
   someprg_wide_output | vim -
   ```

   vim accepts the whole width of the output without wrapping lines

I tried adding `++cols` option, it does not seem to work as expected

```
:terminal ++cols=300 someprg_wide_output
```

Is there a way to make vim terminal think it is wider as visible part?
I would like output looks in 1. like it does for 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No one has replied at all to this? Hmm. Well, I think I have an answer ("works for me") Note: `++cols` won't do anything if the terminal window already takes up the full width of the surrounding Vim window.

Refer to the help section on [terminal resizing](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#terminal-resizing). It discusses how to use the [`'termwinsize'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#'termwinsize') option to control terminal window dimensions. For your needs try a value that uses the *rows*columns* format. For example, if you do `:set termwinsize=20*200` a subsequent `:terminal cmd` for a command that outputs text will not force line breaks into any lines that fit into 200 columns or less.

If you reset with `:set termwinsize&` and try again then the width will go back to being constrained by Vim window width.

That's it.

Comment: I've been using a workaround by redirecting output to a file and opening it afterwards - wrapped that actions into vim functions. 
Just out of curiousity - what is the natural way of figuring out there's a termwinsize option?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by a "natural way". Really you just need to search for the obvious. In this case I just did `:h :terminal` and then `/size` and that immediately took me to a link to the terminal-resizing section that I mention in my (updated) answer. My general advice is a) understand that Vim's help is outstanding but you'll be better equipped to use it if you b) read [user guide entry on help](https://vimhelp.org/usr_02.txt.html#02.8) to learn important information about how the docs are navigated and pick up some important conventions (e.g. `'foo'` vs `:foo` vs etc.).

Comment: The way you described I'd call natural. As an opposite to getting answers vie SE.
Now it really looks easy to find. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @TagWint Cool. Glad that helped. Cheers.